# Increment value by index in ngFor - Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem with incrementing value in ngFor. I have two methods for increment and decrement, the code is below. NgFor is really long so I will post only ts file and HTML which has increment and decrement actions. My ngFor goes like this *ngFor="let product of catalogProducts. The main problem is that when I want to increase the value of input in ngFor, but it updates all inputs in ngFor...

TS file

```
@Input() counterValue = 0;

increment(index) {
    this.counterValue++;
}
decrement() {
    if(this.counterValue <= 0) return false;
    this.counterValue--;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="incrementer">
    <div class="column">
        <button (click)="decrement()">
            -
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <input class="count" [value]="counterValue" [(ngModel)]="product.quantity" />
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <button (click)="increment(index)">
            +
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess it has to do with scope, you should remove `this` unless `counterValue` is within object's scope

Comment: What is the problem? https://plnkr.co/edit/w8bU61vt3zkLloyEfX8k?p=preview

Comment: I updated my question about main problem.

Comment: Please check plunker above

Comment: Okay, it works when you have quantity in an object, but what will happen when you don't have? You will get NaN